# Using Lombok's @SuperBuilder with GSON's fromJson throws nullPointerException parsing JSON in a complex inheritance structure

Tags: java, json, javafx, gson, lombok

Inheritance structure is as follows:
`Child > Parent > SuperParentBuilderEnabler > (3rd party) RecursiveTreeObject<Parent>`

Using Gson's `fromJson(obj, Child.class);`
function works fine when creating the object however adding to `ObservableList<Parent>` it causes an error, I don't think the
`RecursiveTreeObject<Parent>` constructor is initialized properly and as a result of this when I use it with `TreeItem<Parent> root = new RecursiveTreeItem<>(tree, RecursiveTreeObject::getChildren);`
I get a NullPointerException.

At this point I'm certain that the `RecursiveTreeObject<Parent>` isn't getting extended properly but I'm not sure if there's limitations to the `Gson.fromJson(obj, Child.class)` functionality.

Test1: I like to be able to do this but it gives me errors:

```
        Child child = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, Child.class);
        tree.add(child);
```

Test2: This will run without errors but requires me to specify the all the fields

```
        Child child2 = Child.builder().field1(jsonObject.get("field1")
                .getAsString()).field3(jsonObject.get("field3").getAsString())
                .build().init();
        tree.add(child2);
```

I would like to be able to do this via `Test1`.

All the classes and dependencies are below.

SuperParentBuilderEnabler class

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.datamodels.treetable.RecursiveTreeObject;

public abstract class SuperParentBuilderEnabler extends RecursiveTreeObject<Parent> {
    public static abstract class SuperParentBuilderEnablerBuilder<
            C extends SuperParentBuilderEnabler,
            B extends SuperParentBuilderEnablerBuilder<C, B>
            > {
        protected abstract B self();
        public abstract C build();
    }

    protected SuperParentBuilderEnabler(SuperParentBuilderEnablerBuilder<?, ?> b) {
        super();
    }
}
```

Parent class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@SuperBuilder()
@Data
public class Parent extends SuperParentBuilderEnabler {
    @Expose
    protected String field1;
    protected SimpleStringProperty field2;

    public Parent init(){
        setField2(new SimpleStringProperty(field1));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Child class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@SuperBuilder()
@Data
public class Child extends Parent{
    @Expose
    protected String field3;

    public Child init(){
        super.init();
        return this;
    }
}
```

Main class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.jfoenix.controls.RecursiveTreeItem;
import com.jfoenix.controls.datamodels.treetable.RecursiveTreeObject;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;

public class Main {
    public static final String JSON = "{\"field1\": \"test1\", \"field3\": \"test3\"}";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(JSON).getAsJsonObject();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        ObservableList<Parent> tree = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        TreeItem<Parent> root = new RecursiveTreeItem<>(tree, RecursiveTreeObject::getChildren);

        Child child = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, Child.class);
        tree.add(child);

        Child child2 = Child.builder().field1(jsonObject.get("field1")
                .getAsString()).field3(jsonObject.get("field3").getAsString())
                .build().init();
        tree.add(child2);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>StackOverflow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hildan.fxgson</groupId>
            <artifactId>fx-gson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Someone is inappropriately voting 'close' - this is plenty of detail.

Comment: JSON (de)marshallers are rather finicky. I know that Jackson (the slightly more popular competitor to the GSON project) is sufficiently finicky and weird that it requires all sorts of non-standard things. Lombok has a [`@Jacksonized`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized) annotation that you stick on classes together with (Super)Builder to tell lombok to generate a bunch of jackson config annotations so jackson knows what to do. I assume Gson wants similar strange things, but we don't have a @Gsonify (yet - contributions welcome).Perhaps what @Jacksonized does will help?

Comment: Thanks @rzwitserloot, I believed I posted enough information and even provided code that I singled out from the main application I'm working on. I will look at Jacksonized, as well as look into some deserializers; I'll post back here if I find anything regarding a solution I for what I looking for or a work around to achieve the desired implementation.

Comment: I’m not an expert on Lombok, and I know a little GSON. Both these frameworks play very badly with JavaFX. (In my opinion, and it is an opinion, neither Lombok nor GSON properly understand what encapsulation is.). In particular, AIUI, Lombok will create a `setField2(SimpleStringProperty)` method, which is obviously not what you want (you want to set the value wrapped by `field2`, ie `setField2(String)`). And similarly, GSON will attempt to serialize `field2` itself, listeners and all, instead of serializing its *value*.

Comment: If you’re using JavaFX, I’d recommend Jackson over GSON, as Jackson will let you serialize *properties* (GSON only supports serializing fields). And I’d abandon Lombok entirely, as it basically can’t distinguish between properties and fields. (Specifically, you can’t have a property called `x` without having a field called `x`.) This is all opinion; please don’t flame. Or at least point me to a working example of using Lombok in conjunction with the JavaFX property pattern.

Comment: @James_D I’ll take a look at this; with the current design structure for my javafx app; it works just fine for all other uses. I haven’t ran into an issue with serializing and deserializing fx properties as they’re updated at runtime and are always changing when the application is running however this is because there’s a default field that doesn’t change that initializes the fx property.

Comment: @Zera42 “There’s a default field that doesn’t change…” So why use a JavaFX property at all? The whole purpose of JavaFX properties is to allow for you to register listeners or bindings that react when they change. If they’re not changing, what’s the point?

Comment: If you replace the entire property (`setField2(SimpleStringProperty)`) then any listeners or bindings you’ve registered won’t work (they’re listening to a property that’s no longer referenced), and indeed won’t even react to that invocation of `setField2(…)`. And again, if you don’t have listeners or bindings on the property, what’s the point in using it in the first place? Just use a regular `String` field.

Comment: What I mean is; for my specific application say there’s; a String a which is a user defined string that is basically a constant once defined that I save and load from the disk. Then there’s StringProperty b that gets initialized with a and is bound to the UI (table) that needs to constantly update.  @James_D

Comment: Again, if it’s constant once initialized, what is the point in using a `StringProperty` instead of just a `String`???? There’s absolutely no point in registering a listener with something that doesn’t change.

Comment: The StringProperty does change.

Where the String is loaded from disk and needs to stay the same until the user changes it.

Comment: Off topic, but every conversation I have with anyone using Lombok just reinforces my first impression that it’s utterly stupid. All it seems to do is replace boilerplate code. It does nothing that any self-respecting IDE can’t do, with the (absolutely massive) disadvantages that my source code is not in sync with my compiled code, and that if I want to modify my code to do something other than the boilerplate I am completely and utterly screwed. If you want to generate boilerplate code, use an IDE to explicitly generate it, not compiler hacks.

Comment: @Zera42 But if you use Lombok, it will replace the `StringProperty` instance, not update the existing instance’s value. The argument still applies. No listeners that are registered will be notified, because the original `StringProperty` instance’s value hasn’t changed.

Comment: @James_D you're not wrong; however check my parent class as it'll show my implementation to properly create a new `StringProperty` instance with the value passed in from child. That's currently my work around and works just fine. This is also the reason I'm using `@SuperBuilder` at the moment. In theory the solution I'm looking for will allow me to specify which fields will be exposed by `Lombok` and it'll create the constructor for that automatically; as well as allow me to call a custom constructor to initialize the properties after as a hook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243686/discussion-between-zera42-and-james-d).